# JLabel change text if JDialog is visible

Tags: java, jlabel, actionlistener

I want to change the text of the Jlabels on the JDialog(other class) when the button is clicked.

This code is a bit long because i'm just new on java. Please bear with me

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class HotelRoomsGUI extends JPanel{
    private JTabbedPane mainJTP;
    private JPanel classicTab,deluxeTab,presidentialTab,classicSubPanel,deluxeSubPanel,presidentialSubPanel;
    private String classicRoomNo[] = {"101","102","103","104","105","106","107","108","109","101","111","112"};
    private String deluxeRoomNo[] = {"201","202","203","204","205","206","207","208","209","201","211","212"};
    private String presidentialRoomNo[] = {"301","302","303","304","305","306","307","308","309","301","311","312"};
    private JButton[] classicRoom, deluxeRoom, presidentialRoom;
    private JLabel[] inputLabels;
    ButtonHandler bh;
    public HotelRoomsGUI(){

        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(new Color(90,90,90));
        add(tabbedPane());

    }
    public JPanel classic()
    {
        classicTab = new JPanel();
        classicTab.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        classicTab.setLayout(null);
        classicSubPanel();
        return classicTab;
    }
    public JPanel classicSubPanel()
    {
        classicSubPanel = new JPanel();
        classicSubPanel.setBounds(10,10,605,455);
        classicSubPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,10,10));
        classicSubPanel.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        classicTab.add(classicSubPanel);
        return classicTab;
    }
    public JPanel deluxe()
    {
        deluxeTab = new JPanel();
        deluxeTab.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        deluxeTab.setLayout(null);
        deluxeSubPanel();
        return deluxeTab;
    }
    public JPanel deluxeSubPanel()
    {
        deluxeSubPanel = new JPanel();
        deluxeSubPanel.setBounds(10,10,605,455);
        deluxeSubPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,10,10));
        deluxeSubPanel.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        deluxeTab.add(deluxeSubPanel);
        return deluxeSubPanel;
    }
    public JPanel presidential()
    {
        presidentialTab = new JPanel();
        presidentialTab.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        presidentialTab.setLayout(null);
        presidentialSubPanel();
        return presidentialTab;
    }
    public JPanel presidentialSubPanel()
    {
        presidentialSubPanel = new JPanel();
        presidentialSubPanel.setBounds(10,10,605,455);
        presidentialSubPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,10,10));
        presidentialSubPanel.setBackground(new Color(70,70,70));
        presidentialTab.add(presidentialSubPanel);
        return presidentialSubPanel;
    }
    //Holder of buttons
    public JTabbedPane tabbedPane()
    {
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.ORANGE); 
        mainJTP = new JTabbedPane();
        mainJTP.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
        mainJTP.setBounds(3,1,630,500);
        mainJTP.addTab("Classic",classic());
        mainJTP.addTab("Deluxe",deluxe());
        mainJTP.addTab("Presidential",presidential());
        rooms();
        return mainJTP;
    }
    //Labels that will be display on the RoomProfile class
    public JLabel[] inputLabels()
    {
        inputLabels = new JLabel[10];
        for(int x = 0; x<inputLabels.length;x++)
        {
            inputLabels[x] = new JLabel();
            inputLabels[x].setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        return inputLabels;
    }
    public void rooms()
    {
        bh = new ButtonHandler();
        presidentialRoom = new JButton[presidentialRoomNo.length];      
        deluxeRoom = new JButton[deluxeRoomNo.length];
        classicRoom = new JButton[classicRoomNo.length];
        for(int x = 0;x<classicRoomNo.length;x++){
            //classic rooms
            ImageIcon imageC = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\John\\workspace" +
                    "\\SystemTest\\src\\Images\\classicRooms.JPG"); // image
            classicRoom[x] = new JButton(classicRoomNo[x],imageC);
            classicRoom[x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            classicRoom[x].setBorder(new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY),
                    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY)));
            classicRoom[x].addActionListener(bh);
            classicSubPanel.add(classicRoom[x]);
            //deluxe rooms
            ImageIcon imageD = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\John\\workspace" +
                    "\\SystemTest\\src\\Images\\deluxeRooms.JPG"); // image
            deluxeRoom[x] = new JButton(deluxeRoomNo[x],imageD);
            deluxeRoom[x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            deluxeRoom[x].setBorder(new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY),
                    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY)));
            deluxeRoom[x].addActionListener(bh);
            deluxeSubPanel.add(deluxeRoom[x]);
            //presidential rooms
            ImageIcon imageP = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\John\\workspace" +
                    "\\SystemTest\\src\\Images\\presidentialRooms.JPG"); // image
            presidentialRoom[x] = new JButton(presidentialRoomNo[x],imageP);
            presidentialRoom[x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            presidentialRoom[x].setBorder(new CompoundBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY),
                    BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE,Color.GRAY)));
            presidentialRoom[x].addActionListener(bh);
            presidentialSubPanel.add(presidentialRoom[x]);

        }
    }
    public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //to get what button is accessed
            Room room = new Room(e.getActionCommand());
            //get all info using the room no. got from getActionCommand();
            GuestsInfo info = new GuestsInfo(room.getGuestID());
            String data[] = {info.getFirstName()+" "+info.getLastName(),info.getAge(),info.getGender(),
                    info.getContactNo(),"Today",info.getTime(),"Tomorrow",room.getRoomNo(),room.getRoomType()};
            RoomProfile prof = new RoomProfile();
            if(prof.isVisible())
            {
                System.out.print("test");
            }
            else
            {

                //setting text on label
                prof.setVisible(true);
                inputLabels();
                for(int i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                    inputLabels[i].setText(" "+data[i]);
                    System.out.println(""+data[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is the code for the RoomProfile class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RoomProfile extends JDialog{

    private JLabel[] labels;
    JLabel inputLabels[];
    private String topTextLabels[] = {"Fullname","Age","Gender","Address","Contact No","Arrival", "Time in", "Departure","Room No","Room Type"};
    private JButton okB;
    private JPanel subFrame,topPanel, bottomLeftPanel,bottomRightPanel;
    private JLabel designLabel;
    private ButtonHandler bh;
    private HotelRoomsGUI label = new HotelRoomsGUI();
    public RoomProfile() {
        setLayout(null);
        setModal(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
        setBackground(new Color(80,80,80));
        setContentPane(setSubFrame());
        setSize(600,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    public JPanel setSubFrame()
    {
        createLabels();
        buttons();
        designLabel();
        subFrame = new JPanel();
        subFrame.setBounds(0,0,600,500);
        subFrame.setBackground(new Color(90,90,90));
        subFrame.setLayout(null);
        subFrame.add(setTopPanel());
        subFrame.add(setBottomRightPanel());
        subFrame.add(setBottomLeftPanel());
        subFrame.add(okB);
        subFrame.add(designLabel);
        return subFrame;
    }
    public void designLabel()
    {
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Janpol\\workspace\\HotelGUI\\src\\Images\\Account.JPG");
        designLabel = new JLabel(img);
        designLabel.setBounds(380,27,190,190);
        designLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.GRAY,Color.BLACK));

    }
    // this is where i added some of the labels
    public JPanel setTopPanel()
    {
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
        topPanel.setBounds(20,20,350,200);
        topPanel.setBackground(new Color(90,90,90));
        topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.GRAY,Color.BLACK)
                ,"Personal Information",1,2,new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,13),Color.ORANGE));
        JLabel[] top = label.inputLabels();
        for(int x = 0; x<5; x++)
        {
            topPanel.add(labels[x]);
            topPanel.add(top[x]);
        }

        return topPanel;
    }
    // also here
    public JPanel setBottomLeftPanel()
    {
        bottomLeftPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomLeftPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        bottomLeftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.GRAY,Color.BLACK)
                ,"Stay Information",1,2,new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,13),Color.ORANGE));
        bottomLeftPanel.setBackground(new Color(90,90,90));
        bottomLeftPanel.setBounds(20,250,300,140);
        JLabel[] bot = label.inputLabels();
        for(int x = 5; x<8; x++)
        {
            bottomLeftPanel.add(labels[x]);
            bottomLeftPanel.add(bot[x]);
        }
        return bottomLeftPanel;
    }
    // lastly here
    public JPanel setBottomRightPanel()
    {
        bottomRightPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomRightPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        bottomRightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.GRAY,Color.BLACK)
                ,"Personal Information",1,2,new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,13),Color.ORANGE));
        bottomRightPanel.setBackground(new Color(90,90,90));
        bottomRightPanel.setBounds(350,250,200,140);
        JLabel[] right = label.inputLabels();
        for(int x = 8; x<10; x++)
        {
            bottomRightPanel.add(labels[x]);
            bottomRightPanel.add(right[x]);
        }
        return bottomRightPanel;
    }

    public JLabel[] createLabels()
    {
        labels = new JLabel[topTextLabels.length];

        for(int x = 0; x<topTextLabels.length;x++)
        {
            labels[x] = new JLabel(topTextLabels[x]);
            labels[x].setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                    }
        return labels;
    }
    public void buttons()
    {
        bh = new ButtonHandler();
        okB = new JButton("Ok");
        okB.setBounds(400,400,100,50);
        okB.addActionListener(bh);
    }

    public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
                dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the class Room

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Room 
{

    private String roomType, availability, roomNo, Rate;
    private int  guestID;

    private Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement statement = null;

    public Room(){
        try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/3moronsdb","root","");

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Room(int id)
    {
        this();
        try{
            statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM room WHERE guestID=?");
            statement.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                this.guestID = rs.getInt(1);
                this.roomType = rs.getString(2);
                this.roomNo = rs.getString(3);
                this.Rate = rs.getString(4);
                this.availability= rs.getString(5);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
    //Constructor for setting rate
    public Room(String roomTypeL, String roomNoL , String RateL, String availabilityL)
    {
        this();
        try
        {   
            statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into room(roomType, roomNo, rate,availability) values(?,?,?,?)");
                statement.setString(1, roomTypeL);
                statement.setString(2, roomNoL);
                statement.setString(3, RateL);
                statement.setString(4, availabilityL);
                statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();        
            return;
        }
    }
    public Room(String roomNo){
        this();
        try{
            statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM room WHERE roomNo=?");
            statement.setString(1, roomNo);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                this.guestID = rs.getInt(1);
                this.roomType = rs.getString(2);
                this.roomNo = rs.getString(3);
                this.Rate = rs.getString(4);
                this.availability= rs.getString(5);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
    //get guestID from the database
    public int getGuestID(){
        return this.guestID;
    }   
    //getting roomType
    public String getRoomType(){
        return this.roomType;
    }
    //getting roomNo
    public String getRoomNo(){
        return this.roomNo; 
    }
    //getting rate
    public String getRate(){
        return this.Rate; 
    }
    //getting availability  
    public String getAvailability(){
        return this.availability; 
    }
}
```

And Here is the class for GuestInformation

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class GuestsInfo
{
    private String  firstName, lastName, gender, address, time, deposit, age, contactNo, stay;
    private int  guestID;
    private Connection con;
    private PreparedStatement statement;
    //default constructor
    public GuestsInfo()
    {
        try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/3moronsdb","root","");

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public GuestsInfo(int guestID)
    {
        this();
        try{
            statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM guest WHERE guestID=?");
            statement.setInt(1, guestID);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                this.guestID = rs.getInt(1);
                this.firstName = rs.getString(2);
                this.lastName = rs.getString(3);
                this.age = rs.getString(4);
                this.gender= rs.getString(5);
                this.address= rs.getString(6);
                this.contactNo = rs.getString(7);
                this.time= rs.getString(8);
                this.stay = rs.getString(9);
                this.deposit = rs.getString(10);
                System.out.print(firstName +""+ lastName +""+ age +""+ gender +""+ address +""+ contactNo +""+ 
                        time +""+ stay +""+ deposit);
            }   
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public GuestsInfo(String firstName, String lastName, String age, String gender,
            String address, String contactNo, String time, String stay,  String deposit)
    {
        this();
        try
        {   
            statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into guest(firstName,lastName,age,gender,address,contactNo,time,stay,deposit)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");  

                statement.setString(1, firstName);
                statement.setString(2, lastName);
                statement.setString(3, age);
                statement.setString(4, gender);
                statement.setString(5, address);
                statement.setString(6, contactNo);
                statement.setString(7, time);
                statement.setString(8, stay);
                statement.setString(9, deposit);
                statement.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }   
    }
    //get guestID from the database
    public int getGuestID(){
        return guestID;
    }   
    //get firstName from the database
    public String getFirstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }

    //get lastName from the database
    public String getLastName(){    
        return lastName;
    }
    //get age from the database
    public String getAge(){

        return this.age;
    }

    //get gender from the database
    public String getGender(){
        return this.gender;
    }
    //get address from database
    public String getAddress(){
        return this.address;
    }
    //get contactNo from the database
    public String getContactNo(){
        return this.contactNo;
    }
    //get time from database
    public String getTime()
    {
        return this.time;
    }
    //get stay from database
    public String getStay()
    {
        return this.stay;
    }
    //get roomType from database
    public String getDeposit()
    {
        return this.deposit;
    }
}
```

I don't know why the label doesn't show text. Please help me. Thank you in advance
and also thank you for bearing with me

Thanks for the guys who are helping me. Thank you

Comment: What does your code do? Is that an exception at `inputLabels[i].setText(" "+data[i]);` ?

Comment: that suppose to be change the text of the JLabel on the other class when it triggers. The data there is from the database MYSQL

Comment: Fine, so what is the outcome, if you uncomment that row and run the program?

Comment: The label is still the same. i don't know why.

Comment: And what if you comment out the call to `inputLabels();` (two code lines above) and run the thing?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: after the JDialog is closed it print a stack trace

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at HotelRoomsGUI$ButtonHandler.actionPerformed(HotelRoomsGUI.java:151)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with this line here:

```
   JLabel[] bot = label.inputLabels();
```

This is re instantiating all those labels before adding them to the panel. try:

```
   JLabel[] bot = inputLabels;
```

The confusion here is that it's hard to tell from your extracts what is getting executed first but I'm thinking that this is where your unexpected behaviour is occurring.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with your code, you really shouldn't be instantiating labels as a result of an action as far as I can tell. If you want to package up your project and make it available I'll happily  go through it all with you.

Comment: Sorry i'm just starting to learn java. I don't know how to have a good design in programming codes yet. And thanks for the advice

Comment: That's OK, I'm not trying to criticise, I want to help but it's hard to know where to start without a clear idea of the flow of your application.

Comment: A) Can you provide the Room and GuestInfo classes B) What is the assignment? I assume the hotel GUI was provided for you and you were asked to add additional functionality to it of some kind?

Comment: Ok the assignment is Hotel Management System. I must record the time in and time out and all the information of the guest and also computing the total balance of his stay. I'll provide the class room and guestInfo thanks guys for the help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Here's my guess: In your `actionPerformed()` handler, you call `inputLabels();`. That seems to instantiate new array of `JLabel` objects and assign it to `inputLabels` field. But, it **does not** add these objects to a panel. That is only done in `setBottomLeftPanel()`, when creating the labels for the first time.

So, make sure the code in `actionPerformed()` calls `setText()` on the labels defined in `setBottomLeftPanel()` (and already included to the panel).

**EDIT** (after complete code was posted):

There are multiple things that are wrong. Now, to fix your problem:

1) In `RoomProfile`, create a field `JLabel[] bottomLeftPanelFields;` and assign labels you create in `setBottomRightPanel()` to it.

2) Create a getter on that field (`getBottomLeftPanelFields()`)

3) Modify your `actionPerformed()` as:

```
...
JLabel[] bottomLeftFields = prof.getBottomLeftPanelFields();
for(int i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                 bottomLeftFields[i].setText(" "+data[i]);
             }

                //setting text on label
                prof.setVisible(true);
...
```

That is, set the fields BEFORE you calling `setVisible()` (that is where you're modally displaying your Room dialog). 
From this moment on, labels should be displayed.

Some further bits:

a) Probably do a similar thing for the other labels (top, etc).

b) Get rid of both `inputLabels` fields. One gets rewritten with each call of `inputLabels()`, three times while instantiating `RoomProfile`. Other is not needed at all. Also note your `inputLables()` method always creates 10 objects, even though you need different number of labels each time.

c) Perhaps get a tutorial on Swing and Java design patterns (there are some on Oracle website). That helps to understand how to structure things.

Comment: It make sense.. but what exactly will i put on the setBottomPanel()?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing complete code :) One more question: How many times you have `inputLabels()` and `JLabel[] inputLabels` defined in your code? Just once or are there multiple definitions in various classes? If there was just one, then removal of `inputLabels()` call from `actionPerformed()` would fix it I think. But you've already said that resulted in a NPE. So the code is somewhat more complicated.

Comment: Want me to show the code? i really need to debug it badly i need to pass this study tommorow